# Problema para extraer atributo con un valor específico de un XML, usando Python 2.4

Tags: python, xml, dom

Tengo que parsear un xml para que la consulta corra en openBSD con Python 2.4. Necesito extraer las  de un product name y addresslist type en particular (es el último de 19 elementos). Logré hacerlo a través del índice [18] con ElementTree pero es un archivo dinámico que puede cambiar la posición de los datos buscados. Les paso extracto del xml y mi código.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products updated="5/6/2018">
  <product name="ETC">
    <addresslist type="ACME">
      <address>5485:7845</address>
    </addresslist>
  </product>

.... (En el medio hay 18 product)

  </product>
  <product name="THIS">
    <addresslist type="FIND">
      <address>5658:8742</address>
      .....
      .....
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist type="WRONG">
      <address>8965:3254</address>
      .....
    </product>
</products>

Mi código:

from xml.dom.minidom import parse

doc = parse('O365IPAddresses.xml')
product = doc.getElementsByTagName("product")

for producto in product:
    nombre = producto.attributes["name"]
    print(nombre.value)
```

Con esto logro acceder a todos los `product "name"` pero no sé cómo extraer sólo el último de ellos.

Comment: Si por último elemento te refieres al último que tengas en el XML, podrías reemplazar el `for` directamente por esto: `producto = [p for p in product][-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` retorna una lista con los elementos que coinciden con la etiqueta, para obtener aquellos productos cuyo atributo `name` tenga un valor determinado solo debes iterar sobre ella y usar `Element.getAttribute('name')` para compararlo con el valor. Exactamente lo mismo se aplica para `addresslist`:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse


NOMBRE = "THIS"
TIPO = "FIND"

doc = parse('O365IPAddresses.xml')

for producto in doc.getElementsByTagName("product"):
    if producto.getAttribute('name') == NOMBRE:
        for addr_list in producto.getElementsByTagName("addresslist"):
            if addr_list.getAttribute('type') == TIPO:
                for addr in addr_list.getElementsByTagName("address"):
                    print(addr.firstChild.data)
```

Para:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <products updated="5/6/2018">
>
>   <product name="ETC">
>     <addresslist type="ACME">
>       <address>5485:7845</address>
>     </addresslist>
>   </product>
>
>   <product name="THIS">
>     <addresslist type="FIND">
>       <address>5658:8742</address>
>       <address>5658:4562</address>
>       <address>5658:4582</address>
>     </addresslist>  
>
>     <addresslist type="WRONG">
>       <address>8965:3254</address>
>     </addresslist>
>   </product>
>
>   <product name="ABC">
>     <addresslist type="FIND">
>       <address>5485:7845</address>
>       <address>5658:8454</address>
>     </addresslist>
>   </product>
>
> </products>
> ```

Obtendríamos:

> 5658:8742
>   5658:4562
>   5658:4582

---

Para quién pueda usar `xml.etree.ElementTree` (Python >= 2.5) o la biblioteca externa `lxml` se puede simplificar todo usando *xpath*:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET



tree = ET.parse('O365IPAddresses.xml')
addresses = tree.findall('.//product[@name="THIS"]/addresslist[@type="FIND"]/address')

for address in addresses:
    print(address.text)
```

---

```
import lxml.etree as etree



doc = etree.parse('O365IPAddresses.xml')
addresses = doc.xpath('//product[@name="THIS"]/addresslist[@type="FIND"]/address')

for address in addresses:
    print(address.text)
```

Comment: No sé si olvidé decir que se trata de un archivo dinámico, es decir que lo que hoy ocupa un índice determinado mañana puedo ocupar otro. FJSevilla, el output no trae el address de FIND, sino el de WRONG.

Comment: Necesito extraer los address de name="THIS", type="FIND".

Comment: @GustavoMatto he editado la respuesta, creo que ahora si he entendido  lo que buscabas, hemos tenido un malentendido con "es el último de 19 elementos"... El código está probado con Python 2.7 y Python 3 pero Python 2.4 me pilla lejos, no se de ningún cambio en `xml.dom.minidom` relevante para este código pero si algo no funciona comenta. Un saludo.